# Is it possible to install without using the graphical installer?

Tags: system-installation

The graphical installer does not work. After I typed in my information, it showed the slideshow to me, but didn't install ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the alternate installer:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads